# ¿Como buscar si una función con un nombre determinado forma parte de un código?

Tags: shell

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y necesitaría de un comando para bash en el que pudiera saber si un programa contiene entre sus instrucciones una función con un nombre determinado. He visto que a nivel de código se pueden implementar diversos métodos para saberlo, pero me gustaría saber si también es posible mediante consola.

Muchas gracias.(dejo la pregunta original por si me he explicado mal):

**Explica una forma práctica de saber si en un programa ensamblador existe la función
“Juanito” y cómo averiguar si, además de existir, esa función es invocada o no.**

Comment: Para completar la pregunta, deberías mostrar un trozo del código en el que quieras realizar la búsqueda. Leo `ensamblador`, que tiene una sintaxis clara tanto para definir una función como para llamarla.

Comment: No tengo ningun codigo. A modo general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi conocimiento en ensamblador es nulo, pero leí que par definir una función se requiere de la sintaxis.

```
funcion_juanito:
   ...
    (cuerpo de la función)
```

Entonces vemos que "funcion_juanito" está anclada al inicio del renglón y termina con dos puntos ":". Para eso nos puede ayudar una expresión regular y `egrep`.

```
$ egrep -q '^funcion_juanito:' ensamblador && echo existe el procedimiento || echo no existe el 
procedimiento
existe el procedimiento
```

Y en el caso de llamar a la función es algo de la forma.

```
call               funcion_juanito
```

Es decir, la cadena "call", seguida de múltiples espacios y luego el nombre de la función "función_juanito".

Y de nuevo utilizamos una expresión regular sencilla en `egrep`

```
$ egrep -q 'call[[:space:]]+funcion_juanito' ensamblador && echo fue llamada || echo no fue llamada
fue llamada
```

La explicación rápida es que el cáracter `^` ancla, a la cadena subsiguiente, al inicio. Entonces, en `^funcion_juanito` ancla "funcion_juanito" al inicio.

En el caso de `[[:space:]]` es una "clase de caracter" que selecciona los caracteres de tipo "espacio": esto es tab, nueva línea, tab vertical, avance de página, retorno de carro y espacio, y `+` indica que se va a repetir este caracter al menos una vez. `[[:space:]]+`

Comment: podría servirme. desde luego es mas profesional que hacer cat programa | grep juanito